# applescript script runs from command line, but not when saved to app and double clicked

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a script that runs both as an app and from the command line using osascript. In both cases, I want to pop up a "help" dialog. In the case of the app, it should pop up when I double click the app. In the case of the command-line launch, I want it to pop up when I run the script without arguments (eg: osascript myScript.scpt) . The attached script does **not** pop up the dialog properly when I double click the app, but it does work from the command line. If I delete just the *argv* on the first line, and then remove the -- on the second, thereby emulating the existence of argv, it works fine with a double click. That is, the behavior is radically different when I use the supplied *argv* than it is when I don't. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
on run argv             -- if I remove the argv from this line
    --  set argv to []  -- and then comment *in* this line, it works fine
    getDefaults()       -- when I double-click the app

    if (count of argv) = 0 then 
        displayHelp()  -- doesn't display on double click when I use "on run argv"
    else
        processFromCommandLine(argv)
    end if
end run

on displayHelp()
     display dialog "Help!"
end displayHelp
on processFromCommandLine(argv)
end processFromCommandLine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Script App is quitting with error when you double-click because arg is not assigned to a class you can count, but then you try and get its count. Just wrap it in a try block instead.

```
on run argv
    getDefaults()
    try
        get (count of argv)
        processFromCommandLine(argv)
    on error
        displayHelp()
    end try
end run
```

Comment: Using try blocks to test the existence/state of variables is very common in Applescript.

Answer (score 1):

There's almost certainly a better way, but this works:

```
on run argv

    -- Display help.
    if argv = current application or ¬
        argv's class ≠ list or argv's length = 0 then
        display dialog "Help!"
        return
    end if

    -- Do stuff.

end run
```

It looks like the `direct parameter` for the `run handler` is set to...

- [`current application`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW15) when a script is launched as an application.
- [`me`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW4) when run from Script Editor.